# MySQL or XML files or something else?

Tags: mysql, xml, database, parsing

I have a lot of text data broken down into articles and I anticipate once I release this data a lot of people will be viewing it.

So do I let each person query a MySQL database and house the data there or should I use XML and have one article per xml file and just parse it on the fly?

I am using PHP, MySQL.

I think that MySQL would be a lot faster?

What about some other format to store all this data in?

Comment: By articles, do you mean something along the lines of blog entries?

Comment: What's "a lot of people"? Anyway, that's the purpose of databases, I don't see any reason to go through XML parsing for something like that...

Comment: If the content is not subject to change frequently, consider caching your content. That would likely serve fastest regardless of persistent storage method.

Answer (score 0):

All things considered, you should look into NoSQL and [document oriented databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database).

Answer (score 0):

As always, there's more than one way to kin a cat.

One way would be to store the articles into a database and use full text indexes.

You could consider reformatting the data into HTML (that is stored into a structures of files and directories) and index the articles using [nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/about.html), or [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).